# MySQL Update only if table contains value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table which contains tasks, which should be executed at a certain time. For execution the job gets marked by the executor with its workerID. 
With next sql:

```
UPDATE table1.jobs
SET workerID=10
WHERE workerID IS NULL and time < NOW()
ORDER BY time LIMIT 1
```

I can mark the oldest not marked job.

Now I want this to be executed only if there is not already a job marked with workerID 10.

Is this possible within one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `worker_id as Unique key` and you are done.
If workerID 10 is already there in your table your UPDATE  query will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1.jobs 
SET workerID=10 
WHERE workerID IS NULL 
and time < NOW() 
and not exists (select 1 from table1.jobs where workerID=10)
ORDER BY time 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can only mention the table being updated in a `join` clause.  So, you can express what you want as:

```
UPDATE table1.jobs j CROSS JOIN
       (select count(*) as cnt,
               min(case when workerId is null then time end) as min_nulltime
        from table1.jobs
        where workerId = 10
       ) j10
    SET workerID = 10
    WHERE j10.cnt = 0 and j.workerID IS NULL and j.time = j10.min_nulltime
LIMIT 1;
```

Because you cannot use `order by` with a `join` in an `update`, the subquery also calculates the minimum value of `time` when the `workerId` is NULL.  The `limit` is still there, just is case there is more than one row with the same minimum time.